# Count all matched fields in mysql query

Tags: mysql

My question is next: I have a mysql query like this:

```
SELECT student_id, name, email 
FROM student 
WHERE student_id IN ('1', '2', '3') 
    OR name LIKE '%Nick%' 
    OR email LIKE '%gmail.com%'
```

How can I get the number of matched fields in a in the form of a column that mysql returns
Something like this:

```
   ID NAME  EMAIL           MATCHED  
1. 1  Nick  nick@gmail.com  3  
2. 5  Nick  nick@yahoo.com  1  
3. 2  David david@gmail.com 2
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you Sergio Tulentsev for editing my question, looks better now

Comment: No problem. Next time do it yourself :)

Answer (score 7):

It's ugly, but something like

```
SELECT student_id, name, email,
   IF(student_id IN (1,2,3), 1, 0) +
   IF(name LIKE '%Nick%', 1, 0) +
   IF(email LIKE '%gmail.com%', 1, 0) AS matched
etc...
```

should do the trick.

Comment: ugly's the right word.  But I can't come up with better so +1

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
SELECT student_id, name, email, 
     (
        CASE WHEN student_id IN ('1', '2', '3') THEN 1 END +
        CASE WHEN name LIKE '%Nick%' THEN 1 END +
        CASE WHEN email LIKE '%gmail.com%' THEN 1 END
     ) as matched
FROM student 
WHERE student_id IN ('1', '2', '3') 
    OR name LIKE '%Nick%' 
    OR email LIKE '%gmail.com%'
```

Comment: He wants to count matched fields for a row, not total matched rows. I think.

Comment: sorry, this is not what I actually need.

Comment: edited code not working either - matched column has NULL values for all rows

Comment: @levgenii, can you post a schema of your database at sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: thank you, I decided to get result from mysql and then modify the data in the php to the desired look.